# Consistency around the .phar extension in PHP

Tags: php, phar

Kind of simple question, but I'm new to php and have spent too much time trying to google a simple question. I'm using php 5.6 and many guides ([codeception, for example](http://codeception.com/install#.VrQAxTYrLdQ)) talk about running a command like `php vendor/bin/codecept.phar`. My files often don't have the extension and i don't need to use `php` to execute them. Is this just something that evolved out of the language and is now optional?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/intro.phar.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.phar` file is a compressed archive containing one or more PHP files:

> The phar extension provides a way to put entire PHP applications into a single file called a "phar" (PHP Archive) for easy distribution and installation.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

There is no requirement to run it from the command line with `php`, just as there is no requirement to run a `.php` script from the command line with `php`. As long as the file is marked executable and has an appropriate [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) it can be run as a standalone file.

Comment: Thanks- so in terms of the missing extension (from the codeception example), I'm going to assume it was because I used composer to install codeception in my project, which just symlinked it to composer's own codeception library.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The extension is just for humans to more easily identify a file. If it's marked executable the shell will look at the shebang or run the binary code, depending on the type of file.